# Is it possible to "impersonate" a class in logging via aspect?

Tags: spring-boot, logback, spring-aop

I developed an aspect that will log when I enter and exit from a class with the standard format that also logs the class, so something like:

```
2020-03-20 20:05:30.280  INFO 3336 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.a.common.aop.LoggingAspect        : Entering method
```

Please notice that the logging class appears to be "LoggingAspect". Would it be possible, instead, to log the proxied class name?
At the moment I get:

```
2020-03-20 20:05:30.280  INFO 3336 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.a.common.aop.LoggingAspect        : Entering method 
2020-03-20 20:06:30.280  INFO 3336 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.a.my.proxied.Class        : Doing stuff
2020-03-20 20:05:30.280  INFO 3336 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.a.common.aop.LoggingAspect        : Exiting method
```

I would like to always have `c.a.my.proxied.Class` for each line.
Here's my aspect:

```java
@Aspect
@Order(1)
@Component
@Slf4j
public class LoggingAspect {

  @Pointcut("@within(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController)")
  private void controllerInvocation() {}

  @Around("controllerInvocation()")
  public Object logEntering(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable{
     log.info("Entering method");
     Object res = joinPoint.proceed();
     log.info("Exiting method");
     return res;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation for annotation [`@Slf4j`](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/extern/slf4j/Slf4j.html)

```java
@Slf4j
public class LogExample {}
```

will generate:

```java
public class LogExample {
    private static final org.slf4j.Logger log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogExample.class);
}
```

which means that by using the `log` reference , it would always be for `LoggingAspect` in the code shared.

A workaround could be as follows

```java
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import static org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger;

// ...

@Around("controllerInvocation()")
public Object logEntering(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    // Get the logger for the class of intercepted method
    Logger logz = getLogger(joinPoint.getTarget().getClass());
    logz.info("Entering method");
    Object res = joinPoint.proceed();
    logz.info("Exiting method");
    return res;
}
```

Hope this helps

---

Edit : OP requested @kriegaex for an example of his suggestion. I take the liberty to illustrate his suggestions.

Please refer the aop example [section](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-pointcuts-examples) in documentation for more details

```java
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import static org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger;

// ...

@Around("controllerInvocation() && target(myTarget)")
public Object logEntering(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint,Object myTarget) throws Throwable {
    // Get the logger for the class of intercepted method
    Logger logz = getLogger(myTarget.getClass());
    logz.info("Entering method");
    try{
        Object res = joinPoint.proceed();
    }finally{
        logz.info("Exiting method");
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: The answer is correct. If you want to avoid calling `joinPoint.getTarget()` you can let Spring AOP do the job for you by binding `target(myTarget)` to another advice method argument `Object myTarget` and just use `getLogger(myTarget.getClass())` in the advice body. BTW, @R.G, I will clean up your sample code a bit because you use both loggers, which looks a bit chaotic.

Comment: sure @kriegaex . thanks a lot for the review . My intention was to show the difference between both the loggers.

Comment: Done. One more hint: I did not do this in your code, because it is beyond the scope of the question and the OP made mistake (you just copied his code), but in order to make sure that "Exiting method" is getting logged you ought to use `try - finally` in case the intercepted method throws an exception.

Comment: @kriegaex would it be possible to have an example of the binding you are talking?

Comment: @Phate I have incorporated the changes suggested by kriegaex. Just wanted to mention that my answer is correct and kriegaex mentions another way to achieve the same.